# Does "but one" mean "only one" or "except one"?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

Does "but one" mean "only one" or "except one"?

This phrase shows up in the song "Love is an Open Door" from the movie "Frozen". The relevant line is "Our mental synchronization can have but one explanation".

EDIT:
Shouldn't it be "Our mental synchronization can't have but one explanation"?

Comment: It would be nice to say there's but one usage, but one other usage comes to mind.

Comment: _(Be) but `NP`_ means '(be) only `NP`'. _There are but a few of them_ means 'There are only a few of them'. Normally the `NP` is quantified (e.g, _one/thirteen/a few of them_). However, if the phrase is ***all but** `NP`*, **then** it means 'all except one/thirteen/a few of them'. Make sure you know which idiom you're talking about. There are a lot of them, and some have more words than others.

Comment: So "but one" means "only one", but "all but one" means "all except one"?

And why did you but "be" in parentheses? Does the former idiom only work with "be", or does it work with other verbs as well?

Comment: I removed the [n't] because those aren't part of the [lyrics](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Love_is_an_Open_Door) and it is incorrect to add them in this context.

Comment: @David Yes. Both meanings are used, depending on the context.

Comment: Also: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question asks about "all but"; this asks about "but one". The two don't always overlap. As far as this question is concerned, note that the "except" meaning usually happens after a superlative, as in "the last but one".

Answer (score 5):

It means *only one*

BUT: adverb

only, just, simply, merely: St Anton is but a snowball's throw away from Lech. Collins Dictionary

Comment: Or _limiting modifier_ for those who like their adverbs to be words modifying verbs.

Comment: So "I don't love anyone but you" means "I don't love anyone, only you" or "I don't love anyone except you"? Notice the effect the comma has on the nuance.

Comment: But: is used in different contexts and with differential meanings: I suggest you consult a dictionary for reference. 
Prep. 'with the exception of': No one replied but me.
 'other than': nothing but trouble.