# "but one" - the only?, one of many?

Tags: vocabulary

What does "but one" mean in the following sentence – the only? One of many?

> Scientists think the African elephant’s brain structure is **but one** indicator of its intelligence.

Comment: Also see: [Does “but one” mean “only one” or “except one”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165250)

Answer (score 2):

> Scientists think the African elephant’s brain structure is but one indicator of its intelligence.

"But one" in this context could be interchanged with "only one".
The "brain structure" is one , but not the only, "indicator".

In other contexts, "but one" conveys singularity:

> All the books had red covers but one.

Here "but one"  means one book had a cover that was not red.